# Convert one line JSON with special characters to multiline using powershell

Tags: powershell

The main task is to extract multiply JSONs saved in one file.
File contains not valid JSONs
I'm using pattern to select valid part of first JSON. Then, when I use out-file to save it, the extracted data saving in one line.
I used to try convertfrom-json | convertto-json, but it doesn't work correct. Special characters disappearing and JSON looks really bad.
Any suggestion on how to pars JSONs from file to 1,2,3,n.json files will be helpful. Perhaps there is an alternative of regex + pattern method.

Example of trash JSON below

```
\* 001*\

{
    "_field1": "data",
    "field2": "some_data",
    "field3": [],
    "field4": "010",
    "field5": "somedata",
    "field6": "data-data",
    "beginning_of_content": {
        "field7": "data",
        "field8": "data",
        "field9": "data",
        "Another_contents": [
            {
                "field10": 10,
                "field11": "data",
                "field12": "data",
                "Includings": [
                    "497216IWIE@$@*&@",
                    "98421929847252159z_o\"wACCo",
                    "498214921749217947*&^*&^*SD"
                ],
                "field13": "data"
            }
        ]
    }
}

\* 002*\

{
    "_field1": "data",
    "field2": "some_data",
    "field3": [],
    "field4": "010",
    "field5": "somedata",
    "field6": "data-data",
    "beginning_of_content": {
        "field7": "data",
        "field8": "data",
        "field9": "data",
        "Another_contents": [
            {
                "field10": 10,
                "field11": "data",
                "field12": "data",
                "Includings": [
                    "497216IWIE@$@*&@421421421",
                    "9842192984725lkdflkdskfjllerr$#$#",
                    "498214921749217947*&^*&421422"
                ],
                "field13": "data"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title says to convert single line json to multi-line. What you are showing is a file with several multiline json parts in it, so what is the question? Split that file in several json files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-split` with a regex to split your file into the individual JSON documents it contains:

```
$i = 0
(Get-Content -Raw input.txt) -split '(?m)^\\\*.+' -ne '' | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Content -LiteralPath ('{0:000}.json' -f ++$i) -Value $_.Trim()
}
```

- If you have problems with special characters, add `-Encoding` arguments as needed, to both [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content); note that PowerShell never preserves the input encoding, so even if a file has been read correctly with a given encoding, `Set-Content` will use *its* default encoding, which is BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell (Core) 7+, and the system's active legacy ANSI code page in Windows PowerShell.
- Note the use of the `-f` operator in order to produce left-zero-padded filenames such as `001.json`, `002.json` so that lexical sorting also reflects the numerical order.